# Return last 5 digits of a number

Tags: java, string, int

How do you only display the last 5 digits of a number?

Example input:

```
123456789
```

Would return: `56789`

Comment: Converting the number to a string would definitely be a good starting point.

Comment: Alternatively, investigate the `%` operator.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How could one attempt to tackle this problem? Asking for help is absolutely no problem, but you should at least contemplate on what can be done to solve the problem, otherwise there is no point in the homework ;)

Comment: @mjnchards : Does the number always have greater than 5 digits. I mean the input number!!

Comment: There are people who dare to tag homework?? Bravo!!!

Comment: @UmNyobe - most of the time it is added for them hah.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let's assume that required number to convert is an integer. Then you can use a modular mathematic - you can the number convert to the module with base 100 000. That means that only last 5 digits will be kept. The conversion can be done by an operator for remainder of division, the operator is `%`.

The code is:

```
int x = 123456;
int lastDigits = x % 100000;
```

Comment: I've always had trouble understanding the % operator and this cleared a lot of things up!

Comment: @mjrichards well `%` is a remainder after division but you can look at it also as a tool for using modular mathematic with given base.

Comment: It wouldn't be necessary to check if the int is less than 5 digits would it?

Comment: @mjrichards It isn't. That is simple math.

Comment: be advised about the behaviour when the original number contains 0's, e.g. 100456 % 100000 = 456

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the modulus if working with integerss:

```
int someNumber = 123456789;
int lastFive = someNumber % 100000;
```

Something like that

Comment: What exactly is `substr` in Java?

Comment: @JustinSatyr Oh sorry, need to work on reading Tags. My bad :|

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to do the following:

1) [Convert the number to a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html)
2) [Make sure the string has more than 5 digits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29).
3) [If it does, get the last five characters in the string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

The above three steps have links that show you how implement them.  Since this is homework, getting it to work is left as an exercise (channeling my former TA).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer this but for the benefit of those who search here is a working solution:

```java
public static int getLastDigits(int src, int numberOfLastDigits){
    String in = Integer.toString(src);
    String lastDigits = in.substring(in.length() - numberOfLastDigits)
    String out = in.length() < numberOfLastDigits ? in : lastDigits;
    return Integer.parseInt(out);
}
```