# how to print last 4 digits from my 13 digit long

Tags: java

```
package com.nusecond.code;

public class Code {



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Long i=System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

### Last 4 digits

1. Here i"m trying to get last 4 digits of current time in millis
2. the above code gives 13 digit long type number and i want last 4

Comment: Actually this is closer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067341/return-last-5-digits-of-a-number

Answer (score 3):

Use "modulo" operator `%` as follows:

```
    Long i = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Here we format the result to force 4 digits starting with a 0
    // if the long is shorter than 4 digits long (i.e. in case your
    // long looks like 1, 11 or 111 as numbers cannot start with the
    // 0 digit)
    String result = String.format("%04d", i % 10000);
```

Comment: This was due to the fact that a long cannot start with ``0``. The edited answer now formats the output.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long wtf = 10516;
    System.out.println(
      Long.toString(wtf).substring(
       Long.toString(wtf).length() - 4)); // LAST 4 DIGITS
  }
}
```

Output: `0516`